# Angular 2 - Stripping out click function when using [innerHTML]

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to enter some html via typescript using the [innerHTML] tag on the template.

I am trying to put a click function on the html:

```
status = "<img src='assets/hello.png' (click)='hello()' />";
```

But the click function gets stripped away with the console saying:

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

I see a few people have mentioned using "DomSanitizer" but can't find an example which fixes my exact problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular is stripping out **everything** Angular specific if you are using `[innerHTML]`.

If you need something like that, you can create components at runtime like explained in [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960)
or you can use imperative code to add an event handler like

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

someMethod() {
  this.status = "<img src='assets/hello.png' (click)='hello()' />";
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
  this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('img').addEventListener('click', this.hello.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm getting the error "Property 'querySelector' does not exist on type 'ElementRef'.

Comment: Sorry, I missed `nativeElement.`

Comment: Thanks. But if I was to pass an object to my 'hello' function I can't pass the object in via the string way can I?

Comment: What object? You can do `....addEventListener('click', (evt) => this.hello(evt, this.someObject);`

Comment: Thanks :) I just tried it all but it says "EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: It's probably a sanitization issue. https://plnkr.co/edit/xducufDwLTejKGI4RT12?p=preview