# Angular2 innerHTML ignores (click) event

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am working on an mobile application using Ionic2 and Angular2.
I have an API that return json array of strings like below:

```
{ 
"Go to page <a (click)='redirectToAPage(1)'> something </a>",
"Go to page <a (click)='redirectToAPage(2)'> something else  </a>",
"Go to page <a (click)='redirectToAPage(3)'> something else </a>"
}
```

When I run *ngFor over this array and I use

```
<p [innerHTML]="item"></p>
```

It prints the data well, but it removes (click) event.
After passing it through a DomSanitizer Pipe with bypassSecurityTrustHtml function it ignores the event too.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Angular doesn't parse and doesn't apply binding on your html.

Comment: I know that Angular does not do it by default.
I need to do it and I think there must be a way.

Comment: You can create it dynamically or you can use event delegation to catch event

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469350/angular-2-stripping-out-click-function-when-using-innerhtml/43469411#43469411

Comment: Please find the below solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901436/angular-2-binding-events-not-working-when-adding-template-as-innerhtml

Comment: Try to use DomSanitizer (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer). There is method called bypassSecurityTrustHtml(). It should preserve you click events as is.