# Is there a way so i can send input tag from backend to front end?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am using ng2 smart table and there is no way so i can have input out of the box in the columns so i can make that input to be with type file so i can upload images. I will need to send input from back end to front end when i make some api call for example on some route.

I will need response from that api call -  something like:

```
<input (change)="onImagePicked($event)" type="file" />
```

and when this is send to front end, after the api call should initialise some property with that sended
response from back end.

```
// Angular
input;

this.service.getInput().subscribe(input => {
   this.input = input;
});
```

After that when i use this input property in the HTML i should show this input tag

```
{{ input }}
```

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38303065/6513921

Comment: You can use the innerHTML Tag like `<div [innerHTML]="input"></div>`

Comment: For binding the `change` event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37936094/6513921 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43469411/6513921